# Find words in a dictionary db by given set of letters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's think we have a table of meaningful words (like a dictionary), and we have a "set of letters" as an input, and we want to find all the meaningful words found in our source table that are made with the given set of letters, considering that not all the given letters need to be used in the result, but all the letters of the result need to be part of given set of letters.

```
Dictionary
----------
in
ink
inn
inbox

Input: unmin

Result
------
in
inn
```

Comment: This is not really a suitable problem for SQL -- although it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the string into its letters using a recursive CTE and then make sure that the dictionary only has those letters:

```
with cte as (
      select left(@input, 1) as letter, stuff(@input, 1, 1, '') as rest
      union all
      select left(rest, 1), stuff(rest, 1, 1, '')
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select d.word
from dictionary d join
     cte
     on d.word like '%' + cte.letter + '%'
group by d.word
having count(*) = len(d.word)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc965b6d3a72336cb1c43106c71cb75a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and interesting solution. When I checked your code in db<>fiddle, I found a misspelling in declaring input. In my example it's 'unmin' and in your code is 'ummin'. If you give the correct input as mine, the result is not correct.

Comment: @LeaIgness . . . It works with the other `having` clause.